# Arduino Uno to connect with serial 3.3v device

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I have an `arduino Uno` , in which i took out the chip, in order to use it as a serial adapter that speaks with some hardware device (hm-10 bluetooth). I open the arduino terminal tool and send a word.

The hardware device that should speak with Uno, is need `3.3v` to work, but the `arduino Uno` is output `5v` .

1. i was thinking that a resistors divider on the TX of the arduino would do the work, is that correct? (0.66 =  5v /3.3v )
2. even so, when the hardware send data into the arduino Uno board, it will be 3.3v, hence he shouldn't see it- is that correct ? if yes, is there a way to change that ?

Bottom line, how can i (with what i have now) make the  serial connection from the arduino to the hardware on 3.3v and see the results with the termial tool  ?

Thanks .

Comment: u can provide it with separete power source and still connect the tx rx for serial communication between them...

Comment: NO,the serials are 5v into a chip that only accepts 3.3v..

Answer (score 2):

I run a couple of projects just like this. I use three identical resistors with the tx after the first as a voltage divider (ie Atmega TX > resistor > rx device > 2x resistor > GND)

Inbound the chip recognizes voltage above 2.5V as logic HIGH so just connect directly to the atmegas rx and it works!

Thanks @UncleO please see below for correct logic input level

Comment: The minimum level is actually not 2.5 V. It is 0.6*Vcc, which for Vcc = 5.0V is 3.0V. The device running at 3.3 V puts out a minimum of 3.0V on an output pin, so it just barely works, but it does work. (You may have problems if the baud rate is too high.)

Comment: thanks, but actually it won't work ,seems like the arduino doesn't get the input from the Tx of the other device ..

Comment: OK. Just letting you know what happens for me. I got a couple of logic level converters but never ended up needing them. I got a fingerprint scanner and a proximity device working without using the llc, both were 3.3V

Answer (score 0):

Arduino produces 5v **only** if you connect it to a 5+V power source.

I've established a reliable 2 way communication by simply powering Arduino with same low voltage my device require (~4.1v).
I didn't even need any resistors, just connect tx with rx and vise vera.

But as soon as I connect Arduino to USB, it fail to read any input from the device while the device can still get input from Arduino.

Hope that helps